# Border for the layout

Tags: android, border, android-linearlayout

I am trying to make a border around my layout like this

[image: two text areas with rounded borders]

But what i am trying just change the layout color.
Not make any border.

My code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> 

<stroke android:width="1dp"

        android:color="#eedfcc"
        android:background="#000080"/>

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
         android:topRightRadius="8dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Why it does not work out?

Comment: you didnt define your shape kind like this <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

Comment: actually it is not fully rectangle

Answer (score 66, accepted):

try this:

**STEP 1 :** Create the file `layout_border.xml` in your project's drawables directory  (res/drawable/layout_border.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/> 
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

**STEP 2:**

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
     />
```

Comment: Really nice solution. Quick and easy and nicely documented.  Was able to implement easily in Android Studio 2.1.1 also.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file "res/drawable/my_border.xml" and define a shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FF00FF00" />
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
            android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Then add this as a background inside your layout tag:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_border"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

my_edittext_bg

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >    
    <!-- Color of the border -->
    <stroke
      android:width="2dp"
      android:color="#FF0000" />
    <!-- Use this if you want to round your Corners -->
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <!-- Use this attribute if you want add some paddings -->
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
    </shape>
```

Now set this as background of your edit Text

```
 android:background="@drawable/my_edittext_bg"
```

**Solution 2:**

Use this 9-patch drawable as background of your EditText

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/textboxes"
     />
```

And create xml file in drawable folder named 'textboxes' and write this codein that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<stroke
    android:color="#f269be"
    android:width="2dp" />
<solid
    android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Fro rounder corner border, write this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#009FFFFF"/>
<corners android:radius="10px"/>
<padding android:left="1dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" /> 
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#AAAAAA" />
</shape>
```